# Перемещение X по двумерному массиву при помощи функций JavaScript

Tags: javascript, массивы, разработка-игр, перемещение

Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая при вызове её в консоли, будет сдвигать X
по двумерному массиву вправо, влево, вверх, вниз а на место на котором X был раньше, должен
снова ставится пробел. Короче, должна быть игра, в которой функциями можно будет двигать X по игровому полю, которое состоит из пробелов. Вообще не понимаю как мне поступить, я новичок и меня это загнало в ступор.

`

```
    const rows = 6; // Количество рядов
    const cols = 10; // Количество столбцов
    let area = []; // Сам массив

    for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
        area[row] = [];
        for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
            area[row][col] = ' ';
        } 
        // Цикл который создаёт вид игрового поля
    }

    area[0][0] = 'X'; // Расположить X в верхнем левом углу

    for (let row in area) {
        console.log(area[row]);
    }
    // Вывод поля на экран
```

`

[image: Вот как это выглядит в консоли]

Comment: Ну то-есть X должен при вызове функции переместиться вверх или вниз, и так можно будет делать пока не закончиться игровое поле.

Comment: Только вверх-низ? а вправо влево? по какому условию должно определяться движение Х?

Comment: И вверх и вниз и вправо и влево и двигаться он должен на одну клетку в том направлении куда ему указали при вызове функции

Comment: А направление в функцию как должно передваться? Какие коды движения?

Comment: Я не знаю, это одно из того что мне непонятно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если убрать за скобки то, что можно написать более оптимальней, с удалением некоторого дубля кода, то  вот один из вариантов:

Допустим, движение будет задаваться стандартным геймеровским сочетанием клавиш ASDW.

Если надо, что бы позиция X печаталась прям при вызове функции, то перенесите `.forEach(item => console.log(item))` в функцию, заменив `return`

Что ниже написано - мы запоминаем положение символа всякий раз когда его двигаем, а при каждой попытке сдвинуть, проверяем, не уперлись ли мы в край поля.
Текущее положение сохраняем в переменной `coords`

```js
const rows = 5; // Количество рядов
const cols = 6; // Количество столбцов
let area = []; // Сам массив
const symbol = 'X';
const pusto = ' ';

for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
  area[row] = [];
  for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
    area[row][col] = pusto;
  }
  // Цикл который создаёт вид игрового поля
}

area[0][0] = symbol; // Расположить X в верхнем левом углу
const coords = [0, 0];

function move(vector) {
  switch (vector) {
    case 'W':
      if (coords[0] !== 0) {
        area[coords[0] - 1][coords[1]] = symbol;
        area[coords[0]][coords[1]] = pusto;
        coords[0] = coords[0] - 1;
      } else {
        console.log('Выше некуда')
      }
      break;
    case 'S':
      if (coords[0] !== rows - 1) {
        area[coords[0] + 1][coords[1]] = symbol;
        area[coords[0]][coords[1]] = pusto;
        coords[0] = coords[0] + 1;
      } else {
        console.log('Ниже некуда')
      }
      break;
    case 'A':
      if (coords[1] !== 0) {
        area[coords[0]][coords[1] - 1] = symbol;
        area[coords[0]][coords[1]] = pusto;
        coords[1] = coords[1] - 1;
      } else {
        console.log('Край слева')
      }
      break;
    case 'D':
      if (coords[1] !== cols - 1) {
        area[coords[0]][coords[1] + 1] = symbol;
        area[coords[0]][coords[1]] = pusto;
        coords[1] = coords[1] + 1;
      } else {
        console.log('Край справа')
      }
  }
  console.log('-------------')
  return area;
}
area.forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('D').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('S').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('S').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('D').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('A').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('W').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('W').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('W').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('A').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('A').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('A').forEach(item => console.log(item))
move('D').forEach(item => console.log(item))
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень помог :)

Comment: Заходи и не бойся экспериментировать + отладка в руки! )